# What is difference between the two codes mentioned below? Its a simple LCS problem of DSA

Tags: dynamic-programming, lcs

```html
class Solution:
    def longestCommonSubsequ

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

ence(self, text1: str, text2: str) -> int:
dp = [[-1 for i in range(len(text2))]for i in range(len(text1))]
def helper(i, j):
if i < 0 or j < 0:
return 0
if dp[i][j] != -1:
return dp[i][j]
if text1[i] == text2[j]:
dp[i][j] = helper(i-1, j-1)+1
else:
dp[i][j] = max(helper(i-1, j), helper(i, j-1))
return dp[i][j]
return helper(len(text1)-1, len(text2)-1)

Problem link can be found here: https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-common-subsequence/

The code mentioned first does not work, but if I shift the first two statements below then it works. What is the explanations?

class Solution:
def longestCommonSubsequence(self, text1: str, text2: str) -> int:
dp = [[-1 for i in range(len(text2))]for i in range(len(text1))]
def helper(i, j):
if dp[i][j] != -1:
return dp[i][j]
if i < 0 or j < 0:
return 0
if text1[i] == text2[j]:
dp[i][j] = helper(i-1, j-1)+1
else:
dp[i][j] = max(helper(i-1, j), helper(i, j-1))
return dp[i][j]
return helper(len(text1)-1, len(text2)-1)

class Solution:
def longestCommonSubsequence(self, text1: str, text2: str) -> int:
dp = [[-1 for i in range(len(text2))]for i in range(len(text1))]
def helper(i, j):
if i < 0 or j < 0:
return 0
if dp[i][j] != -1:
return dp[i][j]
if text1[i] == text2[j]:
dp[i][j] = helper(i-1, j-1)+1
else:
dp[i][j] = max(helper(i-1, j), helper(i, j-1))
return dp[i][j]
return helper(len(text1)-1, len(text2)-1)

Comment: Please read how to [properly format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your posts

Comment: Why did you tag this as `dsa`?  The `dsa` tag is for `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  Also, please do not use `DSA` in the title, as again, that means `Digital Signature Algorithm`.  In the real world of computing, professionals *say* "Data Structures" and "Algorithms".  It isn't abbreviated.  Also, by not tagging the proper language, your question was not seen by (I guess) Python programmers.  Please reformat your question, and tag the appropriate computer language you're using.